# using devise helper methods in rails 4.1 concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i have a method that uses devises user_signed_in? and current_user helpers. given that this is needed for almost all controllers in the project... it seemed like a great candidate for becoming a rails concern.  however, when I move the relevant code into a concern i get:

```
undefined method 'user_signed_in'?
```

I thought maybe adding include Devise::Controllers::Helpers would help... but that was to no avail.

I trimmed this down to an example that has the mentioned issue and in a controller you would need this:

```
include CheckIt
```

and in the controller concerns directory a check_it.rb that looks like this:

```
module CheckIt
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers

  included do
    before_action self.checkit
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def checkit
      puts "user_signed_in? #{user_signed_in?}"
    end
  end
end
```

and then, as soon as you access some aspect of that controller it will say `undefined method 'user_signed_in?'`

Comment: You might want to consider creating a helper instead - it will have the correct context for calling helper methods out of the box. And yes you can use modules / classes in helpers.

Comment: i guess that is the way i normally would have done it... but then this begs the question... what then is the purpose of concerns if helpers already were there to do this?  is this more a result of needing a helper method and those can not be accessed in concerns?